Can't see Git > Blame (Annotate) in Visual Studio 2022 (17.11.2)?
I apologize for asking a "software related question". But it's really about knowledge of the Git Blame feature in general.
After the experience improvements update in Visual Studio 2022 (17.11.2) in august 2024 <- This was a red herring, the problem is I can no longer see the Git Blame (Annotate) entry - on some files only, other files (that I also have changes on) DO have the Blame option.
How does this integration work? I can't figure out anything in common among the files that don't have Blame? (they definitely do have a long git history, and don't appear as newly added or ignored files in git)
[Edit]: After my initial update of the question and writing comments, I went back to visual studio and now git blame works on ALL files. VS was open all day. All I did before it "got fixed" was I started right-clicking through random files, seeing the git blame in some and not seeing it in others. And I started my git gui program. Somehow that kickstarted some VS git process..? Confused, this never happened before.


The Git Blame option is still there for me - where are you right clicking exactly in this screenshot?

Interesting. I'm right-clicking on a line in a code file. But also I tried right clicking on a file in the Solution Explorer.

I wonder if it has to do with it being an ignored file - I am assuming its an ignored file based on the "Add Ignored File to Source Control..." option.  What about a file that is not ignored/in source already?

oh! I just clicked through a lot of files, and a random 9 files that I'm working on (I have edited and saved), don't have the Blame option, but other files do have it! Including other files that I have also edited. So, the VS update was a red herring, that's not the cause. I just never had/noticed this problem before, and I haven't figured out yet what the files without Blame have in common.

I imagine new (untracked) files/ignored files probably won't have the option.  Basically, anything Git has no history of.

Nope, something very strange is happening. All files have a very long git history, and also  they don't show as newly added or ignored. But plot twist: Just after I finished the previous comment, I went back to VS, and saw the files that didn't have git blame, now HAVE git blame! I can't image it was "it took a long time for git to load" because I had VS open all day. The only thing that "changed" was I started right clicking through files from different assemblies. Oh and I opened my git gui program in the meantime.
